# Why reassigning a string doesn't reduce the memory usage in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, memory

I just noticed that if you don't either clear or replace a string, the memory usage doesn't reduce.

File x.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
raise(RuntimeError, 'A GNU/Linux or an Android system is needed') unless /linux/ === RUBY_PLATFORM.downcase

require 'objspace'
STDOUT.sync = true
GC.start(full_mark: true, immediate_sweep: true)

define_method(:show) { "System Memory Usage: #{::IO.readlines('/proc/meminfo').then { |x| [x[0], x[2]] }
                            .map { |x| x.split[1].to_f }.reduce(:-)./(1024).round(3)} MiB "\
                                "| Available: #{::IO.readlines('/proc/meminfo')[2].split[1].to_f./(1024).round(3)} MiB" }

define_method(:memsize) { |obj| ObjectSpace.memsize_of(obj).to_s.reverse.gsub(/\d{1,3}/).to_a.join(',').reverse << ' Bytes'}
```

File y.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
fail(NoMemoryError, 'Not enough available memory') if ::IO.readlines('/proc/meminfo')[2].split[1].to_i < 600_000
require_relative(File.join(__dir__, 'x'))
puts show

a = '0' * 500_000_000
puts "Memory used by a: #{memsize(a)}"
puts show

a = ''
puts "Memory used by a: #{memsize(a)}"
puts show
```

File z.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
fail(NoMemoryError, 'Not enough available memory') if ::IO.readlines('/proc/meminfo')[2].split[1].to_i < 600_000
require_relative(File.join(__dir__, 'x'))

puts show

a = '0' * 500_000_000
puts "Memory used by a: #{memsize(a)}"
puts show

a.clear

puts "Memory used by a: #{memsize(a)}"
puts show
```

Output of y.rb:

```
System Memory Usage: 2316.289 MiB | Available: 1445.23 MiB
Memory used by a: 500,000,041 Bytes
System Memory Usage: 2795.504 MiB | Available: 966.016 MiB
Memory used by a: 40 Bytes
System Memory Usage: 2795.504 MiB | Available: 966.016 MiB
```

Output of z.rb:

```
System Memory Usage: 2301.359 MiB | Available: 1460.16 MiB
Memory used by a: 500,000,041 Bytes
System Memory Usage: 2780.098 MiB | Available: 981.422 MiB
Memory used by a: 40 Bytes
System Memory Usage: 2303.387 MiB | Available: 1458.133 MiB
```

Now the problem despite assigning a to an empty string, running the file y.rb uses around 500 megs of memory until the program exits.

z.rb clears the string.

This doesn't also clears the memory:

```
a[0..-1] = ''
```

Note that both my program and gnome-system-monitor agrees with the system RAM usage.

Why is this the case? How does clear works when assignment operator doesn't?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`a = ''` and `a.clear` do subtly different things.

`a = ''` creates a new `String` object and assigns it to `a`. The old `String` object is still floating around in memory waiting to be garbage collected.

```
2.4.4 :010 > a = 'foo'
 => "foo" 
2.4.4 :011 > a.object_id
 => 70311739468740 
2.4.4 :012 > a = ''
 => "" 
2.4.4 :013 > a.object_id
 => 70311748786840
```

Note the different object IDs.

`a.clear` clears the existing `String` object.

```
2.4.4 :016 > a = 'foo'
 => "foo" 
2.4.4 :017 > a.object_id
 => 70311748749240 
2.4.4 :018 > a.clear
 => "" 
2.4.4 :019 > a.object_id
 => 70311748749240
```

Note the object ID is the same.

Specifically `clear` calls [`str_discard`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/551ef27490bf380e46453846c040b48596f34a6a/string.c#L2156) which immediately frees the memory allocated to the `String`.

```
static inline void
str_discard(VALUE str)
{
    str_modifiable(str);
    if (!STR_EMBED_P(str) && !FL_TEST(str, STR_SHARED|STR_NOFREE)) {
    ruby_sized_xfree(STR_HEAP_PTR(str), STR_HEAP_SIZE(str));
    RSTRING(str)->as.heap.ptr = 0;
    RSTRING(str)->as.heap.len = 0;
    }
}
```

---

Another way to see the difference...

```
2.4.4 :026 > a = 'foo'
 => "foo" 
2.4.4 :027 > b = a
 => "foo" 
2.4.4 :028 > a.object_id
 => 70311748602540 
2.4.4 :029 > b.object_id
 => 70311748602540
```

`a` and `b` point at the same underlying object.

```
2.4.4 :030 > a = ''
 => "" 
2.4.4 :031 > b
 => "foo" 
2.4.4 :032 > a.object_id
 => 70311748541360 
2.4.4 :033 > b.object_id
 => 70311748602540
```

After `a = ''`, `a` points at a new object while `b` points at the original. This illustrates why `a = ''` cannot free memory immediately, something else might be referencing the original `String`.

If we set that up again...

```
2.4.4 :034 > a = 'foo'
 => "foo" 
2.4.4 :035 > b = a
 => "foo" 
2.4.4 :036 > a.object_id
 => 70311748490260 
2.4.4 :037 > b.object_id
 => 70311748490260
```

But this time use `a.clear`...

```
2.4.4 :038 > a.clear
 => "" 
2.4.4 :039 > b
 => "" 
2.4.4 :040 > a.object_id
 => 70311748490260 
2.4.4 :041 > b.object_id
 => 70311748490260
```

`a` and `b` are still both refer to the same object.

Comment: Well so for even smaller strings, isn't it a good practice to reassign it rather than using the `str.replace('something')` or `str.clear.concat('something')` methods? In other words is it a bad idea to reassign a string or an array rather than clearing and concat some data to it?

Comment: @S.Goswami It is good practice to create a new copy rather than altering an object in place. Altering an object affects everything which refers to that object, like `b` in the example above. This "action at a distance" can cause hard to find bugs. For this reason it's best to treat objects as "immutable", meaning the object does not change; if you want to change it you make a new copy and change that. If you know you have total control over a very large object, and copying it will affect performance, go ahead and optimize. Otherwise make copies and let the garbage collector do its thing.

Comment: @S.Goswami PS `str.replace('foo')` is clearer and a tad more efficient than `str.clear.concat('foo')`. Both result in freeing the original memory and allocating new memory, but `str.replace` does it explicitly whereas with `str.clear.concat` both the reader and Ruby have to jump through a few more hoops.

Comment: @Schwern: In addition to the "spooky action at a distance" problem, re-using objects by mutating them also breaks the fundamental assumptions that modern high-performance generational garbage collectors are built on: 1) objects die young, 2) old objects don't reference new objects, 3) objects aren't mutated. 1 + 2 together are called the "generational hypothesis", 3 is more related to the general performance impact of write barriers / fences / locks / etc. that are required to protect the integrity of the garbage-collected object space.